# How to copy and rename a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that I want to use to partition client access to a database.  I'd like to be able to have one container per client. If I start multiple copies of the container they all have the same name, the only difference being the port the container is assigned to.

How can I copy/rename the containers in such a way that I can differentiate the container without having to consult a lookup table that matches the assigned port to the client?

Comment: I'm still looking a way to rename the container

Comment: This is [an open issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3036).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28068308/1725096

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All containers have a uniq name. When you do `docker ps` You can see that the first column is the ID. You can then manipulate your containers with this ID.

You actually need this ID in order to perform any operation on the container (stop/start/inspect/etc..)

I am unsure of what you are trying to do, but for each client, you can start a new container and then link the container ID with your user ID.

At the moment, there is no container naming within Docker, so you can't name nor rename a container, you only can use its ID.

In future versions, naming for container will be implemented.

Comment: As of Docker 0.6.5 container naming has been implemented, but you cannot provide a name for an existing container. I suspect that this won't be implemented; just stop the container and run a new named instance.

Comment: "just" is a weasel word. I have a case where I want to keep a container around for inspection during debugging, but want to bounce and restart the service in the new named instance. I think what I can do in this case, at least, is snapshot the container and rm it, releasing the name for use in the new named instance.

Answer (score 32):

The [`docker rename`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#rename) command is part of Docker 1.5. Link to commit:
[docker github](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/21a809d9ae0ef8392f37c9262dca93ff31966e22)

Comment: And instead of typing the old (maybe random) container name, one could also use a unique start of the given container id, e.g. `docker rename 646 newname`.

Answer (score 17):

I'm using docker 1.0.1 and the following allows me to rename an image:

```
docker tag 1cf76 myUserName/imageName:0.1.0
```

Comment: But an image is not a container.

Comment: @kojiro right but containers never have friendly names, do they? They're always random strings. So the answer is probably "you can't - but you can save them as images which you can give friendly names to".

Comment: @RobinWinslow they do have friendly names. Note the `--name` flag, or the rightmost column in `docker ps` output.

Comment: @kojiro I never noticed that! Interesting.